# how can I edit a sudoku grid in pygame using mouse and keyboard detection?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, keyboard, grid, mouse

I want to insert values on the sudoku grid, using pygame, editing an internal matrix. If the user clicks an empty cell, I want them to be able to choose a keyboard number and the internal matrix would be updated, with this number in the respective cell. For now, my loop code looks like this:

```
while custom:
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.blit(bgCustom, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN):
            setGrid(board)
```

and setGrid looks like this:

```
def setGrid(board):
    position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x = position[0]
    y = position[1]
    #print(y, x)
    line = x // 92
    col = y // 80
    #print(col, line)
    #print(board)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP   :
            if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                board[line][col] = 1
                print(board)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                board[line][col] = 2
            elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                board[line][col] = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_4:
                board[line][col] = 4
            elif event.key == pygame.K_5:
                board[line][col] = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_6:
                board[line][col] = 6
            elif event.key == pygame.K_7:
                board[line][col] = 7
            elif event.key == pygame.K_8:
                board[line][col] = 8
            elif event.key == pygame.K_9:
                board[line][col] = 9
```

There is no syntax error, but the board remains uneditaded. My guess is that, when the user activates setGrid, the computer immediately tries to detect keyboard input, but the user is not "fast enough" to make the function work. I thought about making some kind of wait function, to wait for keyboard input, but I don't want the user to get stuck in setGrid. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a variable (`clicked_cell`) which is initialized by `None`. Assign a tuple with the line and column to the cell when it is clicked. Reset the variable after the button was pressed:

```py
clicked_cell = None

while custom:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

            line = event.pos[0] // 92
            col = event.pos[1] // 80
            clicked_cell = (line, col)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:

            if clicked_cell != None:
                if pygame.K_1 <= event.key <= pygame.K_9:

                    line, col = clicked_cell
                    clicked_cell = None

                    number = int(event.unicode)
                    board[line][col] = number

    # [...]
```

Comment: That's genius! Thank you so much. Also, I didn't know the keys had some kind of index. I'm gonna use this a lot, instead of a lot of "elif"s, lol